# Why is this differential form bounded by a polynomial function?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I'm working through some lecture notes and I get stuck to understand the following:

Let G be a compact Lie group. Let $p:  M \rightarrow B  $ be a G-equivariat real vector bundle on a compact G-manifold $B$.  Let $\lambda $ be  a G-invariant 1-form on $ M$ such that $\lbrace f_\lambda = 0  \rbrace = B $ where    $f_\lambda : M \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}^*$ is  the G-equivariat map defined by

$< f_\lambda(m) ,X)>:= \lambda_m(X_M(m))$,  $\quad m\in M , X\in \mathfrak{g}.$

Suppose that the 1-form  $\lambda$ is homogeneous on the fibers of M, with strictly positive degree of homogeneity . Then each component of the differential form $(t,m) \rightarrow e^{-itd\lambda_m}\lambda_m$  ( where $t \in \mathbb{R}$) is bounded by a function of the form $P(t,||m||)$, where P is a polynomial in both variables.

What do they mean by saying "each component of the differential form", and why there exists the polynomial P ?

Comment: I don't understand at all. What is $e^{itd\lambda}$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, actually it's not described in the lecture notes I'm reading, but I understand it like this: $d \lambda$ is the exterior derivative of $\lambda$, i is the imaginary complex number and $e^{itd\lambda}$ is the finite sum $\sum_n \frac{ (itd\lambda)^n}{n!}$ .

Comment: Ah, so the components refer to the various odd-degree forms obtained when we wedge with $\lambda$. OK, nonstandard, but that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. But then why  every component is bounded by a polynomial $ P(t, ||e||) $ ?

Comment: What do we know about $\lambda$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin, I'm sorry I did'nt give all information about $\lambda$, since the statement in my post is one of the steps to prove a theorem and I thought that they will not be needed in this particular step! I'll edit my question and add them.